# IoC in Domain Layer

Tags: php, dependency-injection, interface, architecture, inversion-of-control

In my Domain layer I have contract `Hashing`. One of my domain services depends on this contract. At the moment I have injected it within a __construct method.

In infrastructure layer I have implementation of this contract. I have written something looks like IoC container, which creates services with auto wiring injecting.

It all works. But I know that service's dependencies will grow up. I will add much more *UseCases* to them. And there is another one problem -- container injects all dependencies, but we could use only one *UseCase*, so it will do excess job.

Is it ok, if I will inject IoC container itself instead of many parameters, and use it in *UseCases*.

*IoC contract also lies in Domain Layer contracts namespace*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it ok, if I will inject IoC container itself instead of many parameters

No, it is not okay. Supplying any class outside your [Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/) with access to an unbounded set of dependencies is considered an anti-pattern. This anti-pattern is called [Service Locator](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/).

Injecting the container causes the class to take a dependency on a redundant component (the container) and makes it non-obvious what the class's dependencies are. This complicates testing and makes the class dishonest about its level of complexity.

You might be tempted to inject the container to prevent the class's constructor from keep changing, but this is a sign of another problem. Classes that keep getting new dependencies likely violate the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). You will end up with classes with many constructor arguments—a code smell called [Constructor over-injection](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/08/27/on-constructor-over-injection/).